# Redirect echo output to another program stdin

Tags: redirect, pipe, echo, solaris, stdin

I have a program wich has user interaction. Basically when I run it, some output shows few options and I have to press 5, then some other output appear, and then I have to press 5 again to generate an action from the program. To simulate that user interaction with just one line input in a console, I run this:

```
(echo -e "5\n5" && cat) | someProgram
```

I only reached the second view. ¿What I'm doing wrong?

My OS is Solaris and I'm running bash.

Comment: What's your shell?  `echo` can be a shell built-in command.

Comment: @AndrewHenle It's bash.

Comment: Sometimes it works better with a tool like `expect`. Just do `pkg install shell/expect` if you are on a recent Solaris.

Comment: @peterh Unfortunately, I'm not allowed to install `expect`.